# How to do this query?

Tags: sql, select, mysql

I have a mysql table with these columns:

- **ID** (auto-increment)
- **ID_BOOK** (int)
- **PRICE** (double)
- **DATA** (date)

I know two **ID_BOOK** values, example, 1 and 2.

QUERY:

I have to extract all the **PRICE** (of the **ID_BOOK**=1 and **ID_BOOK**=2) where **DATA** is the same!

Table example:

```
1  1  10.00  2010-05-16

2  1  11.00  2010-05-15

3  1  12.00  2010-05-14

4  2  18.00  2010-05-16

5  2  11.50  2010-05-15
```

Result example:

```
1  1  10.00  2010-05-16

4  2  18.00  2010-05-16

2  1  11.00  2010-05-15 

5  2  11.50  2010-05-15
```

**ID_BOOK**=2 hasn't  `2010-05-14` so i jump it.

Thank you so much!

Comment: Please post the code you have written so far. People generally do not like to just write your code for you.

Comment: Is the name `DATA` intentional? It is a date type. It should be named according what it represents, e.g., `PURCHASE_DATE`.

Answer (score 2):

I've taken a guess at how you want hte results odered and you'll need to replace `myTable` with the actual name of your table.

```
SELECT *
FROM myTable
WHERE DATA IN
(
    SELECT
        DATA
    FROM myTable
    GROUP BY
        DATA
    HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
)
ORDER BY
    DATA DESC,
    ID_BOOK,
    ID
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select PURCHASE_DATE, PRICE from table group by PURCHASE_DATE
```

Comment: You would need to wrap `PRICE` in an aggregate function for this to work.  It would also return the row with date `2010-05-14` which Damiano wants to be skipped since there is only one row with that date.

Answer (score 0):

This will give you a slightly different format for the results, but it might be useful:

```
Select 
t1.id as t1_id, t1.id_book as t1_id_book, t1.price as t1_price, t1.data as t1_data,
t2.id as t2_id, t2.id_book as t2_id_book, t2.price as t2_price, t2.data as t2_data
from table t1
inner join table t2 on t1.data = t2.data
and t1.id_book = 1
and t2.id_book = 2
```

You would get :

```
1  1  10.00  2010-05-16  4  2  18.00  2010-05-16
2  1  11.00  2010-05-15  5  2  11.50  2010-05-15
```